# What properties does a mean-ergodic and non ergodic for second moments time series have?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, ergodic

The first and the most trivial example of a mean-ergodic stochastic process is the i.i.d. case:
$$(u_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z} \sim N(0,1)$$

1. The first intuition we have of ergodicity is that the process $(u_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ has no **memory**, since the value of the process at time $t$ is "uncorrelated" with all past values up to time $t − 1$. So intuitively, no memory has to do with no correlation (i.e. ergodicity).
2. Second, no correlation implies new **information**: each element of the time series will contain some information not available from the other elements. Thus, there are new information contained in the new observations, then a single realization of a long duration will be sufficient to obtain a good estimate of its moments (i.e. ergodicity).
3. Finally, the third intuitions have to do with **persistence**. In fact, a stochastic process that is too persistent, it means a strong correlation. So if the process is not too persistent, we say that the process is ergodic.

But in the world of time series we don't have i.i.d. processes. However, according to this [paper (Definition 13)](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/timeseriesconcepts.pdf), we have that the intuitive definition of Ergodicity is if any two collections of random variables partitioned far apart in the sequence are essentially independent.

Mathematically, a covariance-stationary process $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ is mean-ergodic if given a one realization, $(Y_t^{(1)})_{t=1}^T$, of size $T$ is such that:
$$\bar Y = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T Y_t^{(1)} \overset{p}{\to} E[X_t]= \mu, \quad T \to \infty$$
Moreover, the process is said to be ergodic for the second moments
$$\frac{1}{T-j} \sum_{t=j+1}^T (Y_t^{(1)}-\mu)(Y_{t-j}^{(1)}-\mu) \overset{p}{\to} \gamma(j) :=E[(Y_t- \mu)(Y_{t-j}- \mu)], \quad T \to \infty$$
for all $j$.

**Question**

Suppose I have a random process that is mean ergodic but not ergodic for the second moments. So, what does this mean intuitively (or can it be more rigorously) in terms of memory, persistence or enough information in a single realization?